# Is there an alternative to ITScriptNet

Tags: windows-mobile, compact-framework

Is there anyone developing mobile industrial/enterprise/ERP/Inventory type applications who really loves their development tools and can reccommend an alternative to ITScriptNet?

I've recently used ITScriptNet Omni to develop a mobile application on HHP (Honeywell) Dolphin mobile scanner with Windows CE. Prior to that, we developed from scratch in vs2008 and OpenNetCF, which I enjoy working with, but our jr. developers and business partners want something quicker (yeah, I'm a slow developer), easier to understand and more 'canned' than vs2008.

So ITScriptNet does everything we need, and apps are coming together much quicker and easier than when we used vs2008. Their premium version also has nice 'store-and-forward' and remote database functionality.

Trouble is, the price is steep, and deployment has been frought with pitfalls related to installation and licensing/registration. As a paying customer I've also had problems convincing the vendor to let me re-register on a new dev machine that replaced a failed workstation. (I wonder if folks who chose to pirate the app are having these problems?)

Anyway, the time we saved during development is quickly being eaten up with these license and deployment related problems, and I'm open to changing tools, especially if a framework or open-source toolset built on vs2008 is available.

Thanks!

Comment: Jack at ITScriptNet gave us a call after seeing this post, and provided great customer support! 

Nonetheless, considerable time spent in registration phase of this project (time I'd much rather spend developing, testing, sleeping).

My own company will one day face the decision to use a restrictive registration processes (vs. the 'honor' system) for our commercial products. I'm sure that NOT protecting software loses sales, but how many sales are lost when your product is inconvenient for potential customers? Factor in the extra labor/support costs of restrictions.

Any studies on this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have you looked at [NS Basic](http://www.nsbasic.com/ce/)?

Answer (score 1):

I hope i'm not too late. There is an alternative. [Kalipso Studio](https://www.kalipsostudio.com/). Does not have royalties. Has the native SDK for Barcode/RFID (UHF) for Honeywell and Zebra and others. And you can still deploy to Win CE/Mobile Android and iOS.

Comment: any affiliation? [/help/promotion](/help/promotion)